# Building QT Embedded with librt

Tags: qt, embedded, cross-compiling, librt

I'm building QT embedded 4.7 for the OMAP3 platform. at the link stage, it fails because clock_gettime has no symbol. In my own applications in the past, i've solved this by linking in librt. Have i configured QT embedded wrong? how do i get librt to compile in without modifying the make scripts?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer. I added the following to my `qmake.conf` in my mkspec, and it compiles!

```
QMAKE_LIBS_THREAD = -lpthread -lrt
```

Hope this helps someone else.